# Overlay navigation won't come out when I put a background image on the header

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, overlay

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS. 
I'm doing this project with an overlay navigation based from this [codepen](http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/gbXxdx).

Now, after adding a background image on my header container, the overlay would not show up. Here is the code for reference:

```css
       /*--- header and nav ---*/
    
    header{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100ww;
        background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-640-480-6.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    }
    
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        height: 20vh;
        max-width: 90vw;
        font-family: "Work Sans";
        font-weight: 600;
        z-index: 9999;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    /*--- overlay ---*/
    
    .overlay {
        display: none;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: fixed;
        background: #eee;
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 99;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="section group">
            <nav>
                <div class="col span_3_of_12">
                    <div class="vid-btn"><a href="fb.com">Video</a></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_6_of_12">
                    <div class="logo-btn">
                        <a href="fb.com"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_3_of_12">

                    <div class="menu-btn">
                        <a class="btn-open" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <!-- /section group -->
    </header>
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle with your current code state?

Comment: Even completed as snippet it doesn't work at all

Comment: Hi! I finally made it work. I just had to enclose the entire nav and overlay within the header container. Thanks all for replying. :)